# How to get product in DJI Mobile SDK using bridge app on android device

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I connect to RC android device with running bridge app. And run on Android Studio emulator DJI SDK based application. I connect to the bridge app using:`DJISDKManager.getInstance().enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP("192.168.10.102");`connection is successful. But `DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();` don't working. I can't get product.

If I don't use bridge app than `DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();` works as it should and I can get product.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I launched the bridge app on another device(tablet with Android 4.4.2) and it worked. Before that, I was running the bridge app on phone with Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You have use either debug or normal but you are using both 1 and than 2.

1. For Debug :

   ```
   DJISDKManager.getInstance().enableBridgeModeWithBridgeAppIP("192.168.10.102");
   ```
2. Normal :

   ```
   DJISDKManager.getInstance().startConnectionToProduct();
   ```

   link.
   [Sample](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-Android)

Comment: Doesn't work between Android and iOS. For sure, iOS talks another TCP than Android :))